# Add GridView2 into GridView1 row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two Grid View `gridview1` and `gridview2` inside an asp.net page. In order to bind data to `gridview2` the `gridview1` has to bind first because it depends on its `values`.

After finish binding `gridview2` i want to add a new row in `gridview1` and add the entire `gridview2` inside the last row. So it is not possible to do it `onRowDataBound` of `gridview1`.

Is there a way to do that?.

I tried the following but is not working

```
 grdQuestions.DataSource = LoadQuestions();
        grdQuestions.DataBind();

   grdAnswers.DataSource = LoadAnswer(Convert.ToInt32(grdQuestions.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text));
   //GridView2.DataSource = LoadAnswer(2);
   grdQuestions.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(grdAnswers);
   grdAnswers.DataBind();
   grdQuestions.DataBind();
```

Comment: Have you tried gridview's DataBound event? [Check this out](http://forums.asp.net/t/1343965.aspx/1)

Comment: I've read this question several times, and still can't make sense of it.  Think you may need a clearer explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like below :

First create function that bind parent grid.

```
 private void BindParentGrid()
 {
    //Get data from database in dataset.
      ParentGrid.DataSource = dataset;
      ParentGrid.DataBind();

 }
```

Then create function that bind child grid.

```
private void BindChildGrid()
{                       
      //get data from database in dataset2.
       ((GridView)ParentGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Controls[1]).DataSource = dataset2;
       ((GridView)ParentGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Controls[1]).DataBind();
}
```

Then first call `BindParentGrid()` and then call `BindChildGrid().`

this link will also help you : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22928/GridView-within-GridView